# What is the folder structure to work with Javascript MVC framework?

Tags: javascriptmvc

I want to work with Javascript MVC framework to implementing GUI's. what is the folder structure and how do I create that folder structure. what are the steps I have to follow? which server will support to work with Javascript MVC framework.

Comment: What do you mean by "folder structure"? The one of the backend is framework-dependent, and the one in the URL is called *routing*.

Answer (score 1):

You should've checked your resources at your disposal. http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!organizing seems to have the answers you need.

Found another example files structure:

[image]
<sub>(source: [bitovi.com](http://bitovi.com/images/why-jquery-needs-javascriptmvc/folder.PNG))</sub>

As far as server will support javascript mvc framework. Apache and IIS will both support it. So will weblogic and websphere. They will require extensions I'm sure, but some natively support it.

Comment: Thanks amit... I am i need to follow anything to create this folder structure. If it is there Please let me know the process. If you have a time explian me step by step.